# Is there a metric space on $\mathbb{R}$ such that open sets of Euclidean metric space are not open?

Tags: real-analysis, metric-spaces

If $X$ is metric space together with a metric function $d$, we call $U \subseteq X$ open if for all $u \in U$ there is some $\epsilon > 0$ with $B_{\epsilon}(u) \subseteq U$ where $B_{\epsilon}(u) = \{v \in X|d(u,v) < \epsilon \}$.

So, my question is that can we have a metric on $\mathbb{R}$ such that open intervals (of Euclidean metric) are not open in this particular metric we provide? Or, can we prove that open intervals are always open in any other metric? In latter case, of course open intervals can be closed and open.

Comment: Browsing a [relevant wiki page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Equivalence_of_metrics) will tell us that any set that is open in $\Bbb R$ under the standard Euclidean metric will also be open under any other $p$-norm on $\Bbb R$.  So if we can indeed find a metric where an interval of the form $(a,b)$ is open then I guess it'd have to be a "weird" metric.

Comment: @tilper A metric is not necessarily a norm.

Comment: @tilper: In $\mathbb{R}^1$ all the $p$-norms are the same norm.

Comment: @LiLi, I know, but my point was what I ended up adding to my original comment after you made your comment.

Comment: Alright...@tilper

Comment: @NateEldredge, isn't "same" a little misleading?  I know they're all equivalent, but I think the word "same" would imply more than what they are.

Comment: @tilper: No, I literally meant "same".  Try writing them down.

Comment: @NateEldredge, never mind, I was thinking $\Bbb R^n$ in general.  But yes, for $\Bbb R$ they are all the same.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Take a random, totally crazy bijection $h:\Bbb R\to \Bbb R$, then define a metric $d'$ on $\Bbb R$ by making $h$ an isometry from $(\Bbb R, d)$, with the Euclidean metric, to $(\Bbb R, d')$. Or take a bijection $\Bbb R^2\to \Bbb R$, and do basically the same thing.

Comment: I believe that this "probably" works, but how exactly do you choose your bijection to make sure of it?

Comment: @NateEldredge Let $h$ double any rational number, and leave the irrational numbers unchanged, for instance. Then an open $d'$-ball around a rational number $r$ consists of all rational numbers that are Euclideanly close to $r$, and all irrational numbers close to $r/2$. And that's not even the top of the iceberg that is crazy bijections. Of course, many of the most crazy, "explicit" constructions require the axiom of choice.

Comment: @Arthur Thanks!